# How to check all check boxes in checkedListBox wpfToolkit

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, wpftoolkit

I am using checkedListbox control form the wpfToolKit, I want to check all the checkboxes in the list when I press a button but its not working.

Xaml

```
 <xctk:CheckListBox  Command="{Binding CheckBoxClickedCommand}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ChosenFiles,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

ViewModel
     public ObservableCollection ChosenFiles { get; set; }

Model

```
public class ChosenFile{
    public string FullPath { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

I want my checkedListbox to update when I change the IsChecked property can it be done with this control?

Comment: press what button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it

First redefine the 'ChosenFile' class as below to wire with INotifyPropertyChanged interface

```
public class ChosenFile : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _fullPath;
    public string FullPath
    {
        get { return _fullPath; }
        set
        {
            _fullPath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Window.xaml

```
    <Button Command="{Binding CheckBoxClickedCommand}" Width="100"> Check All</Button>
    <xctk:CheckListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ChosenFiles}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedMemberPath="IsChecked" />
```

On the code behind, on the 'CheckBoxClickedCommand' execute method, do this

```
        foreach (var rec in ChosenFiles)
            rec.IsChecked = true;
```

Comment: Thank you but continuation of the problem is :

Comment: Thank you very much :) .I had another problem worth mentioning is that I mistakenly  added a command to the CheckedListBox control itself to handle the checkbox click events. It was not needed as the control magically handles the checkbox click event and binds it to the SelectedMemberPath.